# Getting an error after setting up profile : Data Not Available

Tags: profile, roles

I have set up a profile where I am giving the user access to only one app. And have added all the VF and apex related to this app to the profile. Have not set any role for the user assigned to this profile. I may OWD setting I have all the required object for app as : Public/Read Write. In profile level I have set access to all the fields, objects. When the user try to run my app I am getting the below error.

> Data Not Available
>   The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page.

Can anyone help me to get the solution for this issue. Does I missed any thing out please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

See https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3tKAAS

Salesforce acknowledges the critical bug.